# Settings up multiple monitors from dual VGA card?

Tags: windows-vista, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, pci, addons

I really need help with this. I recently installed a dual VGA graphics card to my 'Packard Bell iMedia B2218 UK'. My computer installed all the drivers automatically and after restarting I checked my device manager it says my integrated and added cards are working properly.

I plugged my other monitor into the added card (2 monitors on the added card as I get black screen from integrated card). The extra monitor shows a identical image to the first, I went onto my display settings to make a extended screen but it only shows one monitor and no option for extended.

I want to know how to get the two monitors extended screen (if it is possible). And if that is possible could I get a third monitor on my integrated card and have a three monitor extended screen.

Comment: Have you tried removing one monitor from the added card? It seems like your pc can't handle 3 monitors or two video cards.

Answer (score 0):

Many integrated graphics do not support dual monitors from an addon card. The integrated card will be disabled by the BIOS. Check the BIOS for VGA settings to see if you can override this. However I don't think you will be able to run three monitors, you should be able do dual monitors on the addon card.

Comment: I have the two monitors plugged into the addon card but I cant find a way to get the to extend one screen. Also I went through my CMOS and could find any settings on video or VGA. Anyone got any ideas on how to get the addon card to recognise it has two monitors plugged into it?

Comment: What type of cables are you using. Are the both the same type?

Comment: yes there both VGA cables, going to the same graphics card it has dual VGA output for them to go into.

Comment: Are they the same monitors as well? Make sure that if there are multiple inputs on the monitors that you have selected the correct input.

Comment: There not the same type of monitor and I have put the cables in right if I didn't then would they both be showing me my computer screen. I just want to be able for them to have an extended screen instead of showing the same screen twice.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my setup when I started. I had to use the graphics card software from ATI to set the monitors up. Windows did not configure the setup correctly. Does your card have software you can use to set up dual monitors.

Comment: No only the card came no disk.

Comment: Who makes the card, did you check their website?

Comment: I'll check the make now

Comment: I checked the website it showed a product from the same line but with a different of output, its says the product include a disk of the drivers but I bought the graphics card second hand =s.

Comment: Thanks for the help I found out that the website allows you to download the software for free I just need to rip out the graphics to find out the exact model. Goodbye.